# How to use WatchServiceDirectoryScanner via configuration without a locker

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am trying to watch a folder tree for new files, and it seems like WatchServiceDirectoryScanner is exactly what I need, but I can't get the configuration to start without a locker without throwing a BeanCreationException. How do I tell it I don't want a locker?

```
<bean id="myScanner" class="org.springframework.integration.file.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner">
    <constructor-arg value="/my/path"/>
    <property name="filter" ref="onceFilter"/>
    <property name="locker"><null/></property>
</bean>
<bean id="onceFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter"/>
```

I don't want to lock files. Do I really need to implement a custom NonLockingLocker?

Comment: I have tried implementing a null-op AbstractFileLockerFilter, but I am still getting the same exception. prevent-duplicates is NOT set. Does filename-pattern cause a similar issue?

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myFileAdapter.source': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The 'filter' and 'locker' options must be present on the provided external 'scanner': org.springframework.integration.file.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner@7b12e52f

Comment: OK, so filename-pattern DOES cause a similar issue as prevent-duplicates, so neither can be used on a inbound-channel-adapter that uses a scanner, and apparently you DO have to create a null-op AbstractFileLockerFilter.

Answer (score 3):

See log message:

> The 'filter' and 'locker' options must be present on the provided external 'scanner': org.springframework.integration.file.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner@7b12e52f

That says that you have not to use `filter` (`filename-pattern` etc.) and `locker` options on the `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`, if you use `scanner` option.

So, just move their references to the `WatchServiceDirectoryScanner`.
Of course, if you don't have `locker`, there is no reason to create some `NoOpLocker`. Just don't declare `<property name="locker">` on the `WatchServiceDirectoryScanner` bean definition.